# Simple calculus question: Can this unflattering equality be simplified further?

Tags: calculus

from a economic model I derived I get the following optimality, which is very unflattering. As my calculus game is kinda rusty, I was wondering if there are possibilities to simplify this further to make it more appealing?

$$ e_i^{bt*}=\frac{γα \frac{35}{36} w(1-t)-\frac{1}{36} A(1-α)+(1-θ)(αγλ \frac{1}{n} tw+λA(1-α))}{\frac{35}{36} w(1-t)+(1-θ)(αλ\frac{1}{n} tw+λtw(1-α))} $$

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using a computer algebra program like wolfram alpha?

Comment: yeah, but Wolfram Alpha just returns an error when a formula with this much variables is inputted

Comment: I do not think, that you can do much... you could take out the lambda out of the last braces in dominator and numinator

Comment: Multiplying both with 36 would get you rid of the fractions

Comment: Also n, but i think, that would not make it easier to read

Comment: If you took out the $t\omega \lamda$ in the lower brace, you would end up with something like $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})\alpha